# Symfony2 Project Runs On Localhost, Has File Finding Problems On EC2

Tags: php, git, symfony, deployment, amazon-ec2

I have a Symfony2 project that uses quite a few 3rd Party bundles. I use Sonata Admin Bundle for the application admin. I am almost finished with my project development and I'm trying to get it live on Amazon EC2. I am using GIT to deploy my application, I have managed to get everything setup but I am coming across a very weird problem. The project is running just fine on the local server but when I get it live I get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Unable to load class "Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin"
```

While trying to run app/console commands I get the Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle' not found in /var/www/html/candulifestyle.com/app/AppKernel.php on line 25

Fatal error: Class 'Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle' not found in /var/www/html/candulifestyle.com/app/AppKernel.php on line 25
```

I'm having a real hard time tracing the problem here. The project is running perfectly on my local system. Has anyone come across a problem like this. Please let me know if anyone has any insight on such a problem.

Comment: Maybe you forget to execute `php composer.phar install` ?

Comment: I actually ended up pushing the vendors along with my git remote push. Because for some reason composer keeps failing to clone on the EC2 instance. As a matter of fact I have now found the problem, My Sonata Bundles are not pushing any code inside them. The only way now is to get the composer install to work.

Comment: I have the same issue on a DigitalOcean instance about the `SonataBlockBundle` not being found, although it is present and `composer install` has been executed. Can't find out why...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same very strange problem (`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle' not found` although it was present in the right folder) on a DigitalOcean server (running Ubuntu 12.04), whereas I didn't have the problem on my Ubuntu 12.04 VM instance.

I finally found the solution to the problem.

I just had to update Composer as I should have already done before:

```
composer self-update
```

And then run again this:

```
composer install
```

And everything was fine again.